# Volver a activar un boton desactivado C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

Hola antes que nada soy un programador principiante (estudiante) me encuentro haciendo el juego del ahorcado, y mi pregunta es la siguiente, hice el código con un método y una condición "if" de manera en la que al presionar cada botón este se desactivara y cambiara de color en el caso de coincidir o no la letra de la palabra en juego, la cosa es que tengo un evento click de un botón que genera un nuevo juego y quisiera saber como hacer para que al ejecutar el evento nuevo juego este me active nuevamente todos los botones usados y vuelvan al color por defecto, para que este mas claro dejo el código del juego. Desde ya muchas gracias y espero puedan ayudarme. Saludos

```
    //DECLARACIONES DE VARIABLES
    private int _cantidadErrores = 0;
    private bool _iniciarJuego;
    private int _cantidadMinimaChar = 3;
    private int _cantidadMaximaChar = 50;

    //CONSTRUCTOR DEL FORMULARIO
    public FormJuego()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //INICIALIZAMOS VARIABLES
        _iniciarJuego = false;
    }

    //======================================================================//
    //========================== EVENTOS PRIVADOS ==========================//
    //======================================================================//

    private void FormJuego_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClearForm();
    }

    private void FormJuego_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtPalabraIntroducida.Focus();
    }

    private void btnComenzar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComprobarExtensionPalabra(txtPalabraIntroducida.Text, _cantidadMinimaChar, _cantidadMaximaChar))
        {
            _iniciarJuego = true;
            txtPalabraIntroducida.Enabled = false;
            btnComenzar.Enabled = false;
            btnNuevoJuego.Enabled = true;

            txtProgreso.Text = ReplicarPalabraEnDisplayConGuiones(txtPalabraIntroducida.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            string mensajeErrorChar = $"La palabra debe tener entre {_cantidadMinimaChar} y {_cantidadMaximaChar} caracteres.";

            MessageBox.Show(mensajeErrorChar);
        }    
    }

    private void btnA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is Button)) return;//Si no sos un boton return(No sigue ejecutando el codigo)

        if (_iniciarJuego)
        {
            ComprobarYReemplazarLetra(((Button)sender).Text , (Button)sender);
        }
        else
        {
            txtPalabraIntroducida.Text += ((Button)sender).Text;
        }
    }

    private void btnNuevoJuego_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        ClearForm();
        txtPalabraIntroducida.Focus();
    }

    private void btnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    //======================================================================//
    //========================== METODOS PRIVADOS ==========================//
    //======================================================================//

    /// <summary>
    /// Metodo para limpiar los controles del formulario.
    /// </summary>
    private void ClearForm()
    {
        txtPalabraIntroducida.Clear();
        txtPalabraIntroducida.Enabled = true;

        txtProgreso.Clear();

        btnComenzar.Enabled = true;

        btnNuevoJuego.Enabled = false;

        _cantidadErrores = 0;
        lblErrores.Text = $"Errores: {_cantidadErrores}";

        _iniciarJuego = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compruba que la palabra cumpla con la extension establecida.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool ComprobarExtensionPalabra(string palabra, int cantidadMinima, int cantidadMaxima)
    {
        if (palabra.Length >= cantidadMinima && palabra.Length <= cantidadMaxima) return true;

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replica la palabra introducida con guiones en el display Progreso
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    private string ReplicarPalabraEnDisplayConGuiones(string palabra)
    {
        string palabraIntroducida = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < palabra.Length; i++)
        {
            palabraIntroducida += "_";
        }
        return palabraIntroducida;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Metodo para comprobar si existe y reemplazar la letra.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Letra"></param>
    private void ComprobarYReemplazarLetra(string Letra, Button botonPresionado)
    {
        if (VerificarSiExiteLaLetra(txtPalabraIntroducida.Text, Letra))
        {
            txtProgreso.Text = ReemplazarLetraEnProgreso(txtPalabraIntroducida.Text, txtProgreso.Text, Letra);

            botonPresionado.BackColor = Color.Green;
            botonPresionado.Enabled = false;
            VerificarSiGano(txtPalabraIntroducida.Text, txtProgreso.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            _cantidadErrores++;
            botonPresionado.BackColor = Color.Red;
            botonPresionado.Enabled = false;
            lblErrores.Text = $"Errores: {_cantidadErrores}";
            MostrarImagenError(_cantidadErrores);
            VerificarSiPerdio(_cantidadErrores);
        }                      
    }

    private void VerificarSiGano(string palabra, string progreso)
    {
        if (palabra == progreso)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ganaste");
        }
    }

    private void VerificarSiPerdio(int cantidadErrores)
    {
        if (_cantidadErrores == 6)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Perdiste.");
        }
    }

    private void MostrarImagenError(int cantidadErrores)
    {
        switch (_cantidadErrores)
        {
            case 1:
                imgImagen.Image = Properties.Resources.Error1;
                break;
            case 2:
                imgImagen.Image = Properties.Resources.Error2;
                break;
            case 3:
                imgImagen.Image = Properties.Resources.Error3;
                break;
            case 4:
                imgImagen.Image = Properties.Resources.Error4;
                break;
            case 5:
                imgImagen.Image = Properties.Resources.Error5;
                break;
            case 6:
                imgImagen.Image = Properties.Resources.Error6;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reemplaza la letra en la posicion correspondiente a la palabra original.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text1"></param>
    /// <param name="text2"></param>
    /// <param name="letra"></param>
    private string ReemplazarLetraEnProgreso(string palabraOriginal, string progreso, string Letra)
    {
        string cadena = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < palabraOriginal.Length; i++)
        {
            if (palabraOriginal[i] == Letra[0])
            {
                cadena += Letra;
            }
            else
            {
                cadena += progreso[i].ToString();
            }
        }            

        return cadena;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Verifica si la letra existe en la palabra y devuelve un bool
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <param name="letra"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool VerificarSiExiteLaLetra(string palabra, string letra)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < palabra.Length; i++)
        {
            if (palabra[i] == letra[0])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }            

        return false;
    }
```

[image: Interfaz grafica]

Comment: Tus botones los creas en el diseño o se crean desde el código? Si sabes cuales son tus botones, en btnNuevoJuego_Click puedes hacer en enable de todos los botones

Comment: En el diseño creo toda la interfaz y luego genero los eventos y el codigo para cada uno, si pense en eso, pero deberia activar y resetear colores de 27 botones, seria mucho codigo, no hay una forma mas generica o corta de hacerlo para todos los botones?

Comment: Si son pocos botones lo puedes hacer como te digo, al entrar en el método btnNuevoJuego_Click haces btn_Comenzar.Enabled = true; btn_...Enabled=true; Si fuesen muchos botones te diría de hacer un array de botones y recorrerlo con un for pero al ser pocos lo puedes hacer así

Comment: Claro vos me decis hacer esto?     btnA.Enabled = true;
            btnA.BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
            btnB.Enabled = true;
            btnB.BackColor = DefaultBackColor;
            ;.......etc hasta el btnZ.

Comment: Te he dejado una respuesta a ver si eso te sirve

Comment: hola tengo una situación muy parecida te importaría mostrar como quedo el codigo con los arreglos en el for?, tengo el mismo proyecto.

Comment: Hola @RamiroToranzos la verdad no lo hice con el for en el evento del btnNuevoJuego_Click hice lo de activar uno por uno todos los botones correspondientes a las letras en mi caso los active y reinicie los colores de cada uno.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu número de botones es limitado, lo que puedes hacer es:

```
botón1.Enabled=true;
boton2.Enabled=true;
...
```

Si tienes más, lo que puedes hacer es esto:

```
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)  //Recorremos todos los controles del formulario
{
    if(c is Button)  //Comprobamos que sea un botón
    {
        c.Enabled = true;  //Lo habilitamos
    }
}
```

Esto tiene que ir dentro del método btnNuevoJuego_Click

```
private void btnNuevoJuego_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    foreach(Control c in this.Controls)  
    {
        if(c is Button)  
        {
            c.Enabled = true;  
        }
    }
    ClearForm();
    txtPalabraIntroducida.Focus();
}
```

Con ese código activamos todos los botones. Siempre puedes poner alguna cláusula si hay algún botón que no quieres activar o desactivarlo después del foreach

Comment: +1 es exactamente lo que estaba pensando sugerirle, el ciclo recorriendo los controles, y si es de tipo `Button` activarlo.

Comment: No me esta funcionando, no me los vuelve a activar al ejecutar 
 el evento btnNuevoJuego_Click, no te voy a mentir el foreach no nos enseñaron al menos por el momento, y como recorrer controles tampoco, estamos muy a lo básico por ahora.

Comment: Si no has tocado el foreach puedes utilizar el for normal (no se si esto lo conoces) haciendo for (int i=0; i<this.Controls.length; i++). Lo necesario es un bucle, si no habéis visto bucles lo tendrás que hacer uno por uno.